# How to access span with needed innerhtml?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, html

Say my WebBrowser1 downloaded a page that has a following line:

```
<span customattr="hamolulu">hamolulu</span>
```

It is inside of a td tag, inside of big table, inside of iFrame, inside of div etc.

How to I click this thing using c# ?

I need to do something following:

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= 500; i++)
{
    if (webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span")[i].GetAttribute("customattr") == "hamolulu")
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span")[i].InvokeMember("click");
        break;
    }//end if
}// end for
```

but for some reason it does not work this way, so I'm thinking if it's possible to check the innerHTML of the span, or innerText?

I tried both:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span").InnerHTML == "hamolulu"
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span").InnerText == "hamolulu"
```

And I failed both times.

Update: 
I just noticed that the line is actually like this:

```
<span customattr="hamolulu"><a>hamolulu</a></span>
```

So I wrote a simple function:

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a").Count - 1; i++)
{
  log(i.ToString()+ " : " +webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")[i].InnerHtml);
} //log(string) is a custom function that saves all strings to a file log.txt
```

And what I've seen is that this link (and span) does not show up in my log.
In other words, getElementsByTagName("span") and getElementsByTagName("a") doesn't see the item. My guess is that it is because of iFrame. Do you have any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another solution using no js (because you don't own the "page")
since it is inside an iframe then you should search within that iframe

```
HtmlElementCollection iframes = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("iframe");
HtmlElement iframe = iframes(0 /* iframe index */); // 

HtmlElementCollection spans = iframe.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
for (i = 0; i < spans.Count; i++) {
    HtmlElement span = spans(i);
    if (span.GetAttribute("customAttr") == "customAttrValue") {
        string onclick = span.Children(0).GetAttribute("onclick"); //span.Children(0) should return the <a>
        WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript(onclick);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, and this is what I've just did, but the getElementsByTagName doesn't see the needed span / a (check out Update)

Comment: can you provide a link to the page you are trying to work on ?

Comment: I just found a problem. It's iFrame. When I try to log its innerhtml, it is returned empty, though firebug does see it. I'll probably open a new question, as this one is getting too big and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something...

```
<span id="hamolulu">hamolulu</span>
```

Then when you want to change it...

```
document.getElementById('hamolulu').innerHTML="<h1>Test!</h1>";
```

Comment: I need to make it in c#, not in JavaScript. But thanks anyway.

Comment: oh, and hamolulu is not an ID - it's custom attribute and innerhtml at the same time, so GetElementByID won't work.

Comment: @SerhyiVynohradov, That's why in my example, I changed it to `id`.  I'm not sure why you would want to do what you're doing.

Comment: Because I don't own the site, so I can not change that to ID, and the only thing that makes this span unique is this attribute.

Comment: Then if it were me, I'd use jQuery:  `$('select[customattr="hamolulu"]').text("new text");`

Answer (score 0):

you can make it simpler by using JavaScript and invoking it from c# whenever you need to.

```
WebBrowser1 .Document .InvokeScript ("functionName")
```

javascript:

```
function functionName(){

  var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('SPAN');
  for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)
  {
    var span = spans[i];
    if (span.getAttribute("customattr") == "hamolulu")
    {
        eval(span.getAttribute('onclick')); // .. be careful "span" has no "click()" method. you should use the onlick attribute if available
        break;
    }//end if
  }// end for
}
```

Comment: But where to do I put this javascript code? How to put it into my c#? As a simple string?

Comment: try to add it to the page using a script tag

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your span as an HTML server control:

```
<span runat="server" id="myspan" customattribute="customvalue">hello world</span>
```

Then you can register an event handler on page load:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myspan.Attributes["onclick"] = "this.innerText='hamolulu'";
    }
```

Another way to do it is using Page Methods which would call a page C# method using AJAX.