# Access element in child master page from parent master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a parent master page, child master page and content page.

In the content section of the child master page i have :

```
<span runat="server" id="CustomSpan"></span>
```

I need to add some string into the innerHTML attribute of this element.

parent master page code behind:

```
string text = "<span class='SpanRight'>test</span>";
CustomSpan.InnerHtml = text;
```

the problem is that it doesn't find the element:
"the name 'CustomSpan' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: Irena what have you tried..? look at this previous Stackoverflowpost http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000537/how-to-access-span-with-needed-innerhtml

Comment: How would the parent master page even know whether or not the child has that field?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to understand your question.  If you are wondering how a master page can access the elements on child pages, in code behind, I made a post about it [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/03/27/master-page-child-pages-dynamic-communication-flexibility.aspx).

Comment: I am wondering what to do in case that I need c# function/class that I can call when the page loads and it can access to page elements. I thought that if I put the code in the parent master page it could access to the page elements, but it doesnt. I don't want to repeat the code in every nested master page for that to work.